# Determining the time complexity for code segments

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, notation

What is the time complexity for each of the following code segments?

```
1. int i, j, y=0, s=0;
for ( j = 1; j <= n; j ++) 
{
  y=y+j;
}
for ( i = 1; i <= y; i ++) 
{
  s++;
}
```

My answer is O(2n) since it iterates through each loop n times and there are two loops

```
2. function (n) {
  while (n > 1) {
  n = n/3 ;
}
```

My answer for this one is n^(1/3) since n becomes a third of its size every time

```
3. function (n) {
int i, j, k ;
for ( i = n/2; i <= n; i ++ ) {   //n/2?
  for ( j = 1; j <= n; j = 2*j ) {  //logn
    for ( k = 1; k <= n; k = 2*k ) {  //logn
      cout << ”COSC 2437.201, 301” << endl;
    }
  }
}
}
```

I said the answer to this one was O(log2*log2n*n/2) but I'm pretty confused about the first for loop. The loop only has to iterate half of n times, so it would be n/2 correct? Thanks for your help, everyone.

Comment: Firstly, `O(2n)` is just `O(n)` - and that is the wrong answer for question 1.

Comment: What about the first for loop is confusing you exactly?

Comment: How could the first segment be anything besides O(n)?  

For the first loop, the loop only has to iterate half of n times, so it would be n/2 correct?

Comment: What about the second loop? It depends on the value of `y` after the first loop, right? What would that be?

Comment: "n^(1/3) since n becomes a third of its size every time" Non sequitur.

Comment: [so] is not really a good place to be verifying the correctness of your homework answers. That's what your teacher and textbook is for. Also, try to stick to 1 question per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**

The first loop is `O(n)`, as it runs `n` times. *However*, the second loop executes `y` times, not `n` - so the total runtime is not "`2n`"

At the end of the first loop, the value of `y` is:

[image]

Therefore the second loop dominates since it is `O(n^2)`, which is thus also the overall complexity.

---

**Question 3**

This answer is correct (but again, drop the factors of `2` in O-notation).

However, you must be careful about naively multiplying the complexities of the loops together, because the boundaries of the inner loops may depend on the spontaneous values of the outer ones.

---

**Question 2**

This is *not* `O(n^(1/3))`! Your reasoning is incorrect.

If you look closely at this loop, it is in-fact similar to the *reverse* of the inner loops in question 3:

- In Q3 the value of `k` starts at 1 and is multiplied by 2 each time until it reaches `n`
- In Q2 the value of `n` is divided by 3 each time until it reaches 1.

Therefore they both take `O(log n)` steps.

(As a side note, a `O(n^(1/3))` loop would look something like this:)

```
for (int i = 1; i*i*i <= n; i++)
   /* ... */
```

Comment: Helping people with homework is OK, but avoid *doing* it for them.

Comment: @n.m. you're right; I think OP may need some more explanation than could be squeezed into a comment though

Comment: I mean I'm not just trying to get answers.  Your answer is the only one that really helped me understand what was going on.  Thank you.